# why meteor npm install --save angular-ui-grid dont work?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, meteor, npm, angular-meteor

I have a very big problem, with meteor npm install, I using:

- Meteor Angular
- Meteor

I try to import `ui-grid` like `uiRouter` or `angularUBoostrap` (as you can see in the image). But is imposible. Is not the first time that I try to import some packages installed by 'meteor npm install', sometimes good, sometimes error. **why**? and how can I solve this? please, I really, really, really I need install uiGrid with 'meteor npm install'
**Please, help!.**

[image]

this is the entire menssage error in navigator console:

```
modules.js?hash=b73ee78…:3830 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ageApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module {} due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'module' is not a function, got Object
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/areq?p0=module&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20Object
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:3830:12
    at assertArg (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:5654:11)
    at assertArgFn (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:5664:3)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8388:11
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:4083:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8363:5)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8380:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:4083:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8363:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8285:19)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=%7B%7D&p1=Error%3A%20%5Bng%3Aareq%5D%20Argument%20'module'%20is%20not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20Object%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.8%2Fng%2Fareq%3Fp0%3Dmodule%26p1%3Dnot%2520a%2520function%252C%2520got%2520Object%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A3830%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20assertArg%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A5654%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20assertArgFn%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A5664%3A3)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8388%3A11%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A4083%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8363%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8380%3A40%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A4083%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8363%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8285%3A19)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:3830:12
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8402:15
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:4083:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8363:5)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8380:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:4083:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8363:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8285:19)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:5520:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:5541:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=ageApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20Failed%20to%20instantiate%20module%20%7B%7D%20due%20to%3A%0AError%3A%20%5Bng%3Aareq%5D%20Argument%20'module'%20is%20not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20Object%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.8%2Fng%2Fareq%3Fp0%3Dmodule%26p1%3Dnot%2520a%2520function%252C%2520got%2520Object%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A3830%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20assertArg%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A5654%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20assertArgFn%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A5664%3A3)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8388%3A11%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A4083%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8363%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8380%3A40%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A4083%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8363%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8285%3A19)%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.8%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3D%257B%257D%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255Bng%253Aareq%255D%2520Argument%2520'module'%2520is%2520not%2520a%2520function%252C%2520got%2520Object%250Ahttp%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.5.8%252Fng%252Fareq%253Fp0%253Dmodule%2526p1%253Dnot%252520a%252520function%25252C%252520got%252520Object%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fpackages%252Fmodules.js%253Fhash%253Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%253A3830%253A12%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520assertArg%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fpackages%252Fmodules.js%253Fhash%253Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%253A5654%253A11)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520assertArgFn%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fpackages%252Fmodules.js%253Fhash%253Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%253A5664%253A3)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fpackages%252Fmodules.js%253Fhash%253Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%253A8388%253A11%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520forEach%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fpackages%252Fmodules.js%253Fhash%253Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%253A4083%253A20)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520loadModules%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fpackages%252Fmodules.js%253Fhash%253Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%253A8363%253A5)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fpackages%252Fmodules.js%253Fhash%253Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%253A8380%253A40%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520forEach%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fpackages%252Fmodules.js%253Fhash%253Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%253A4083%253A20)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520loadModules%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fpackages%252Fmodules.js%253Fhash%253Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%253A8363%253A5)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520createInjector%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fpackages%252Fmodules.js%253Fhash%253Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%253A8285%253A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A3830%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8402%3A15%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A4083%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8363%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8380%3A40%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A4083%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8363%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8285%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20doBootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A5520%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20bootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A5541%3A12)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:3830:12
    at assertArg (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:5654:11)
    at assertArgFn (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:5664:3)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8388:11
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:4083:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8363:5)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8380:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:4083:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8363:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8285:19)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=%7B%7D&p1=Error%3A%20%5Bng%3Aareq%5D%20Argument%20'module'%20is%20not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20Object%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.8%2Fng%2Fareq%3Fp0%3Dmodule%26p1%3Dnot%2520a%2520function%252C%2520got%2520Object%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A3830%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20assertArg%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A5654%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20assertArgFn%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A5664%3A3)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8388%3A11%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A4083%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8363%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8380%3A40%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A4083%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8363%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8285%3A19)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:3830:12
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8402:15
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:4083:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8363:5)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8380:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:4083:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8363:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8285:19)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:5520:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:5541:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=ageApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20Failed%20to%20instantiate%20module%20%7B%7D%20due%20to%3A%0AError%3A%20%5Bng%3Aareq%5D%20Argument%20'module'%20is%20not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20Object%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.8%2Fng%2Fareq%3Fp0%3Dmodule%26p1%3Dnot%2520a%2520function%252C%2520got%2520Object%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A3830%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20assertArg%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A5654%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20assertArgFn%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A5664%3A3)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8388%3A11%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A4083%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8363%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8380%3A40%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A4083%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8363%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8285%3A19)%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.8%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3D%257B%257D%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255Bng%253Aareq%255D%2520Argument%2520'module'%2520is%2520not%2520a%2520function%252C%2520got%2520Object%250Ahttp%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.5.8%252Fng%252Fareq%253Fp0%253Dmodule%2526p1%253Dnot%252520a%252520function%25252C%252520got%252520Object%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fpackages%252Fmodules.js%253Fhash%253Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%253A3830%253A12%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520assertArg%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fpackages%252Fmodules.js%253Fhash%253Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%253A5654%253A11)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520assertArgFn%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fpackages%252Fmodules.js%253Fhash%253Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%253A5664%253A3)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fpackages%252Fmodules.js%253Fhash%253Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%253A8388%253A11%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520forEach%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fpackages%252Fmodules.js%253Fhash%253Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%253A4083%253A20)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520loadModules%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fpackages%252Fmodules.js%253Fhash%253Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%253A8363%253A5)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fpackages%252Fmodules.js%253Fhash%253Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%253A8380%253A40%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520forEach%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fpackages%252Fmodules.js%253Fhash%253Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%253A4083%253A20)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520loadModules%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fpackages%252Fmodules.js%253Fhash%253Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%253A8363%253A5)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520createInjector%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fpackages%252Fmodules.js%253Fhash%253Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%253A8285%253A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A3830%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8402%3A15%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A4083%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8363%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8380%3A40%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A4083%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8363%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A8285%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20doBootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A5520%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20bootstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fpackages%2Fmodules.js%3Fhash%3Db73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f%3A5541%3A12)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:3830:12
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8402:15
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:4083:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8363:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:8285:19)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:5520:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:5541:12)
    at angularInit (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:5426:5)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=b73ee7873484799229a6d88f4293000c7ed10f7f:35525:5)
    at fire (http://localhost:3000/packages/jquery.js?
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Angular modules don't play nice. If the module doesn't export the right thing (ie the name of the angular module), it will break.

Instead of this code:

```
export default angular.module('ageApp',[    
    angularMeteor,
    angularUBoostrap,
    uiRouter,
    uiGrid
])
```

Try using 'ui.grid' instead of uiGrid, like this:

```
export default angular.module('ageApp',[    
    angularMeteor,
    angularUBoostrap,
    uiRouter,
    'ui.grid'
])
```

It is not a huge deal, but I have had to do this in a few cases myself.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answere. I tried to implement your advice, but I have no good news. The same problem persist. the is a other way to solve this?
Thanks again!

Comment: You could try this meteor package https://atmospherejs.com/smrsoftware/angular-ui-grid

Comment: Yeah but is v3.0.0 actually I have it installed. But I need the actual versión uiGrid 4.0.0.

Comment: Right, that's the problem with Atmosphere packages. You could do the upgrade in a local package

Comment: Thanks for your help. ui-grid repair the problem. I re-installed ui-grid with $meteor npm install --save angular-ui-grid,  and works now! the version installed is 4.0.2 (oficial version) 
Again thanks for your help!